# How can I specify between models of different apps but the same name, in the same view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a separate Django app for two different cities. I have models of the same name, for each of those cities, and would like to bring them into the same view. When i import the models of both apps, the data doesnt render, i assume because Django doesnt know which one to use. 
When I import just corpus_christi, the template renders the data just fine, and vice versa.
How can I specify from which app i want to bring these models?

**Here is my view**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from corpus_christi.models import Service, Member
from lake_charles.models import Service, Member



def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')


def corpuschristi(request):
  residential = Service.objects.filter(service_type="Residential")
  commercial = Service.objects.filter(service_type="Commercial")
  prelisting = Service.objects.filter(service_type="Pre Listing")
  members = Member.objects.all()

  context = {
    'members': members,
    'residential': residential,
    'commercial': commercial,
    'prelisting': prelisting
  }
  return render(request, 'pages/corpuschristi.html', context)


def lakecharles(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/lakecharles.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
from corpus_christi.models import Service as corpus_service
from corpus_christi.models import Member as corpus_member
from lake_charles.models import Service as lake_service
from lake_charles.models import member as lake_member
```

And then call them as needed.